# Generate PDF with CakePhP?

Tags: php, pdf-generation, cakephp-2.0, tcpdf, dompdf

I want to generate PDF with Cakephp. search for google, i see to lib [DOMPDF](https://code.google.com/p/dompdf/) and [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/). I would like to know what are the advantages and what is the fastest way to generate a PDF.

Comment: personally I use DOMPDF for a year, I remember that setting up TCPDF seemed a bit tougher back then, don't know how it stands now. https://github.com/fdeschenes/cakephp-dompdf-view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the two libraries you inquired about, both libraries are fairly robust and have a number of common features:

- HTML rendering
- Font subsetting
  -

Additionally, each library has it's strengths and weaknesses.

[dompdf](http://dompdf.org):

Pros:

- Robust support for HTML and CSS2.1 with some support for features of CSS3. dompdf is designed to provide web browser class rendering capabilities. It's not quite to that point, but it is getting there.
- Works with two back end rendering libraries: a customized version of the PHP-based CPDF (included with the library) or PDFLib (offers better performance). Both of these libraries can be accessed during rendering to allow for direct access to the PDF for manual PDF layout and manipulation.
- Set it up and go. Once you have dompdf set up you only need feed in your HTML and it will return a PDF.

Cons:

- Not as many official releases, though the core code is still updated. If you're more tolerant of unreleased code you can grab the latest directly from github.
- Some bugs around handling of tables (one of which is fairly serious).
- Some documents can require fairly significant system resource to render.

[TCPDF](http://tcpdf.org):
*(I don't use the library, so maybe somebody who does can build out this section.)*

Pros:

- Updated often
- Relatively speedy

Cons:

- Designed for laying out a PDF directly. I hesitate to list this as a con, however, in that it does have fairly decent HTML/CSS support.

---

For working directly with HTML documents there are additional PHP-based libraries such [HTML2PDF](http://html2pdf.fr/en/default) and [mPDF](http://www.mpdf1.com). Or you can use something like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/), which is a headless webkit binary (meaning it also has full support for JavaScript).